Reasons for a colony to use Arcologies
So I was thinking of working on a planet for a scifi setting.
The basic conceit is: it's set in the future, technology has advanced to the point where fusion power is cheap- bordering on free- and there are thousands of habitable planets people have colonised.
What I want is a planet- a habitable garden world people can drink the water and breath the air- except most of the population live in arcologies (massive structures which function like self-sufficient cities), while a minority live outside in towns.
The problem is, I can't think of a good reason why people on this world (and not on most others) prefer arcologies to conventional cities.
Anyone have any ideas?

Wikipedia has a good intro to arcologies. It might be a good idea to start there.

You want people in archeologies for the ecological benefits/lowering the footprint of the people. What is wrong with that as reason for preference?

We're not a brainstorming site for sharing or generating ideas. Questions with many equally valid answers are not permitted here. This is doubly so when it is a question about the motivations of characters or organizations within your world.

To expand on sphennings' comment, your reasons could compass; social, religious, climatological, ecological or reasons to do with malign incursions for example - and an infinity of other reasons. That has interesting possibilities, but is way underspecified for this site's ways. You need to make more decisions about the story's setting and what you want to achieve before asking.

The  biggest problem here isn't the brainstorming per-se, it's that in this case there are so many possible reasons that we can' t ignore Stack Exchange's rules. Maybe your planet has a ubiquitous Tsetse-style fly that causes incurable sickness. Maybe the world is claimed by aliens and they'll only let the humans stay if they live in arcologies. It's the worst form of open-ended. In your case, you need to seriously narrow the question or, better still, you need to tell us why and we'll help you rationalize the reason.

Power is cheap, that's fine, but it has little to nothing to do with how people live, who owns the land, and if they can get away with limiting others access and use of it why wouldn't they, I'm not even sure why you think you have a problem, if the landowners want the land for other uses and arcologies are a thing why wouldn't they cram everyone in them and keep most of the land for themselves, sounds like a character decisions and motives issue to me, and we don't do those.

Power is free. Roads are not. And neither is the time of a commuter.
With the Covid pandemic, many workers in the West realized just how great remote work can be. Less than a minute from the breakfast table to the work desk. Yet management is pushing back, they want their workers where they can see them, and where the workers can see each other. (In all fairness, the latter is a valid point. A workplace is just not the same when the colleagues are tiny images on a screen.)
An arcology can give you the best of both worlds. People live near their workplaces.
